# page footer is not displayed as i desire

Tags: jasper-reports

Hy so my problem is while using jaspersoft studio 2.0 i am creating a file format in which i want to show my page footer section only when the total pages of the report are equal to 1 for which i tried many method but the one which slight successful "$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() ==1" while using this it shows me that section only when the total pages are more then 1 but i want to it when the total pages are 1.
And i don't have any sub report in it.

i tried several other expressions as well in "Print when expression" which are:

```
expression#2:$V{abc} == 1

expression#3:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 1

expression#4:$V{REPORT_COUNT} ==0 && $V{PAGE_NUMBER} ==1

expression#5:$V{abc}==$V{PAGE_COUNT}

expression#6:$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() ==1

expression#7:$V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue() == $V{abc} && $V{abc} == 1

expression#8:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 0 && $V{abc} == 1

expression#9:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1

expression#10:$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() > 1

expression#11:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{PAGE_COUNT}

expression#12:$V{PAGE_Count} == 1

expression#13:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{abc} == 1

expression#14:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 0

expression#15:$V{PAGE_COUNT} == $V{abc} && $V{abc} == 1

expression#16:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 || ($V{PAGE_COUNT} == 1 && $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{PAGE_COUNT})

expression#17:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $V{PAGE_COUNT} > 1

expression#18:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{PAGE_COUNT}

expression#19:$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 || $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 1
```

expression#1:$V{abc}.intValue() ==1